# Matlab plot multiple marker colors

Tags: matlab, colors, marker

I am generating many (thousands) of plots using very large data. I need a very simple way to make my markers different colors, but each element needs to keep it's color. In my main **for** loop I have:

`for i = 1:finaltime
 plot(pos(i,:), track(i,:), 'o', 'MarkerSize', 9) ;`

Where "pos" tells the position of the element (there are 1000) and "track" specifies the track number the element is on (there are 4). So I need 1000 different colors for each marker (which corresponds to each column) in the matrix "pos", which is *finaltime* by 1000 in size. For every figure generated (there will be *finaltime* of them), I'd like the 1000 elements to maintain their colors. For example, the first element in "pos" is blue throughout the simulation. The second element is red, etc.

Comment: you probably can generate the RGB values for the colors separately then paste them into an array in your code. even a simple python script to output RGB values

Comment: Perhaps you can generate a colour map (`colormap`) with 1000 entries, then pick off a row / colour for each track you want to plot.

Comment: OK, now I get it.  Is it my understanding that you would like each column of `pos` and corresponding column of `track` to be assigned to the same colour?   Basically, each row of `pos` and `track` has 1000 points, where each point should be assigned a different colour.  For each row that you plot, you want to make sure that the colour scheme is the same for all rows.  If that's the case, then you need to plot the columns and apply the colour map accordingly.

Comment: Do you require any further assistance?

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion I have is to generate a colour palette that is 1000 elements, then for each set of observations you have, simply set the marker to one colour within this colour palette.

If I understand you correctly, you have a matrix where each pair of columns for `pos` and `track` are to have unique colours.  Basically, each row of `pos` and `track` has 1000 points, where each point should be assigned a different colour. For each row that you plot, you want to make sure that the colour scheme is the same for all rows. If that's the case, then you need to plot the columns and apply the colour map accordingly.

As such, do something like this:

```
c = jet(1000);
figure; hold on;
for idx = 1 : 1000
    plot(pos(:,idx), track(:,idx), 'o', 'MarkerSize', 9, 'Color', c(idx,:));
end
```

`jet` is the MATLAB command that generates a colour map default to MATLAB (pre-2014).

There are other colour maps you can explore, and the full list is shown here:

[image]

If you want to use another colour map, simply use the name and call it as a function, with an integer as an input.  This integer will give you that many colours within the confines of that colour map.  As such, say if you wanted the `hsv` colour map with 256 colours.  You would do this:

```
c = hsv(256);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that this will turn every marker the same color, and then at the next index turn them all a different color, etc. The "for" loop runs over time for the positions of elements on a track. So at every time it is reading the positions, plotting them, reading the positions, plotting, etc. It is going from 1:200,000 for example. So somehow all 1000 of the elements in "pos" need to be assigned their own color.

Comment: @LuckyPenny - I didn't understand this from your original problem statement.  Please update it so that it's more clear.  Once I actually understand what your problem is, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @LuckyPenny - I've updated my answer.  Hopefully I understand you now.  Let me know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is actually very easy... if I just use `scatter` instead of `plot`, the `scatter` function can take in an array of colors, whereas `plot` can only take one color at a time. So I just changed the code to:

```
scatter(pos(i,:), track(i,:), c );
```

Where `c = rand(n,3)` and specifies the colors. Thanks!